# redirect to appropriate URL based on bookmark

Tags: vb.net

need to redirect to french url if user tries to access the application from default-f.aspx and redirect to the English URL if they come from default-e.aspx.  Currently it redirects to English URL if they come from any bookmarked page from the app.

Comment: Post some code. If these are two separate physical pages it shouldn't be a big deal. If you're using URL aliasing or something, that's trickier. It's really tough to give advice if you don't have some code for us to look at.

Comment: Ok sorry new to this site.  I will post some code later as I am now on vacation until next week.  thank you